# Generating a random number in JavaScript and passing it to an HTML input tag

Tags: javascript, html

My script, stored as a separate js file:

```
function randomNumber(len) {
    var randomNumber;
    var n = '';

    for(var count = 0; count < len; count++) {
        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        n += randomNumber.toString();
    }

    return n;
}

var finalSequence = randomNumber(9);

document.write('<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="ACCOUNT" VALUE='+finalSequence +' MAXLENGTH=16 SIZE=16>');
```

I have included this `td` tag in my html file:

```
<td align=left><FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica"><script src="nexgen.js"></script>
```

Do you suggest that I write my script inside the html file itself?

I would like to display the generated random number using an `input` tag, such as that below. How do I do this?

```
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="ACCOUNT" VALUE= ???  MAXLENGTH=16 SIZE=16>
```

Update:

I am combining the JavaScript and html in one html file as follows. Please see if you can find any mistakes because the number generated is not being displayed on html page.

Javascript part:

```
function randomNumber(len) {
    var randomNumber;
    var n = '';

    for(var count = 0; count < len; count++) {
        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        n += randomNumber.toString();
    }

    document.getElementById("ACCOUNT").value = n;
    return n;
}
```

HTML part:

```
<tr>
  <td><FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica" color="red"> Transaction ID: </font></td>
  <td align=left>
    <FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica">
      <script> randomNumber(9); </script>
      <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="ACCOUNT" ID="ACCOUNT" VALUE="" MAXLENGTH=16 SIZE=16 readonly>
    </font>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I am combining the javascript and html in one html file. as follows. please see if you can find any mistakes because the number generated is not being displayed on html page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign an ID to your input element, then in your JavaScript, assign the generated value to that element.

```js
function randomNumber(len) {
  var randomNumber;
  var n = '';

  for (var count = 0; count < len; count++) {
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    n += randomNumber.toString();
  }
  return n;
}

document.getElementById("ACCOUNT").value = randomNumber(9);
```

```html
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="ACCOUNT" ID="ACCOUNT" VALUE="" MAXLENGTH=16 SIZE=16>
```

**Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5u8f/).**

Comment: while the logic seems to be correct.thanks, but the number is not displaying for my html. only an input box is being displayed      <td><FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica" color="red"> Transaction ID: </font></td>
<td align=left><FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica"><script src="nexgen.js"></script>
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="ACCOUNT" ID="ACCOUNT" VALUE=""  MAXLENGTH=16 SIZE=16>                                                </font></td>      My html lines for displaying the number generated.

Comment: @user3329255 I assume your script is in _nexgen.js_? Make sure that the function is called on document ready or window load--e.g. `window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("ACCOUNT").value = randomNumber(9);
};` See the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5u8f/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, but you can do that in different ways:

http://jsbin.com/hujefopa/1/edit

```js
function rand(len){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(10, len));
}

function setRand(){
   document.getElementById('rand').value = rand(9); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body onload="setRand()">
  <input type="text" id="rand">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

BTW, if you want to generate a random number of a certain length, you can do it in much bigger chunks than one digit at a time, e.g.:

```
function longRandom(length) {
  var n = '';
  while (n.length < length) {
    n += ('' + Math.random()).split('.')[1];
  }
  return n.substr(0, length);
}

console.log(longRandom(42)); // 134434793311713322660940870849409308530315
```

will do it in chunks of about 15 digits on each loop. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that:

1. If your script is small, it's better to put it inside the page itself rather than importing a new file (new request to the server).
2. Using `document.write` is not recommended. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice).
3. To update the value of html input you can use:

   ```
   document.getElementById('id-of-your-input-element').value = newValue;
   ```

   or using jQuery:

   ```
   $('#id-of-your-input-element').val(newValue);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

A random number is generated using javascript and also passed in the input form tag in html using code similar to ones mentioned below.

Javascript :

```
function randomNumber(len) {
    var randomNumber;
    var n = '';

    for(var count = 0; count < len; count++) {
        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        n += randomNumber.toString();
    }
    return n;
}

window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("ACCOUNT").value = randomNumber(9);
};
```

HTML part:

```
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="ACCOUNT" ID="ACCOUNT" VALUE=""  MAXLENGTH=16 SIZE=16>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML PART

```html
    <tr>
    <td><FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica" color="red"> Transaction ID: </font></td>
    <td align=left>
    <FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica">
    <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="ACCOUNT" ID="ACCOUNT" VALUE="" MAXLENGTH=16 SIZE=16 
    readonly>
    </font>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

JavaScript Part

```
     <script>
    document.getElementById('ACCOUNT').value=Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    </script>
```